# Tensorflow build: Used --config=ios but while building the file on Xcode it says binary built for macOS

Tags: ios, xcode, tensorflow, bazel

I am trying to build a specific folder in tensorflow/lite/experimental. I cloned tensorflow and ran the ./configure command and gave yes for building with iOS support. I built my folder using bazel build --config=ios //tensorflow/lite/path to folder. It got built successfully but when I added these binaries to Xcode and tried to build it for testing on iOS simulator, it says "Building for iOS simulator but linked item 'is_finite_test' was built for macOS.

I used the file command to check the executable type, it says: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64.
I tried using --config=ios_fat but i get the same error.
I'm also really new to Xcode,I just installed it yesterday.
Upon using the command below,
otool -l  | grep platform
I get the output to be Platform 1,meaning it's compiled for macOS.Why is it compiled for mac despite using the --config=ios or --config=ios_fat.
I'm using a Macbook Retina with Intel m3 processor. Am I getting this error because I'm not using an ARM based Mac?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.